# Magento Block Paypal Rewrite

Tags: php, magento, paypal, block

I try to rewrite core file from Magento. But after rewrite the block it was not accessible and I don't know why?

The File I try to rewrite is : **Mage_Paypal_Block_Standard_Redirect**

The xml config (locate: app/local/Ga/etc/config.xml) :

```
<global>
    <models>
        <ga>
            <class>Ga_Model</class>
        </ga>
    </models>
    <blocks>
        <ga>
            <class>Ga_Block</class>
        </ga>
        <paypal>
            <rewrite>
                <standard_redirect>
                    Ga_Block_Paypal_Standard_Redirect
                </standard_redirect>
            </rewrite>
        </paypal>
    </blocks>
    <helpers>
        <ga>
            <class>Ga_Helper</class>
        </ga>
    </helpers>
</global>
```

The custom block (locate: app/local/Ga/Block/Paypal/Standard/Redirect.php):

```
class Ga_Block_Paypal_Standard_Redirect extends Mage_Paypal_Block_Standard_Redirect {
    protected function _toHtml()
    {
        return 'test';
    }
}
```

Paypal controller call the block like that :

```
public function redirectAction()
{
    $session = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session');
    $session->setPaypalStandardQuoteId($session->getQuoteId());
    $this->getResponse()->setBody($this->getLayout()->createBlock('paypal/standard_redirect')->toHtml());
    $session->unsQuoteId();
    $session->unsRedirectUrl();
}
```

"createBlock" method return nothing after the rewrite.

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong.

### Thanks

**EDIT :**
I have found the solution. The problem come from the fact it's necessary to write the custom block class in one line like that :

```
    <blocks>
        <ga>
            <class>Ga_Block</class>
        </ga>
        <paypal>
            <rewrite>
                <standard_redirect>Ga_Block_Paypal_Standard_Redirect</standard_redirect>
            </rewrite>
        </paypal>
    </blocks>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Follow this structure

```
<global>
<blocks>
    <paypal>
        <rewrite>
             <standard_redirect>MyNamespace_MyModule_Block_Standard_Redirect</standard_redirect>
        </rewrite>
    </paypal>
</blocks>
<global>
```

Comment: Thanks but that don't rewrite at all. It's like doing nothing it don't take the config in consideration because we are not suppose to add the class node.

Comment: @BrunoMaurice: i am sorry for this mistake...are you using any namespace for your module? see my updated code

Comment: You have answer well just when I found the solution. Thanks ;D